# failed to load fecs_inst

Tags: boot, 16.04

Back from vacations, I tried to start my computer. It shows the ubuntu name for a while than falls into emergency mode. Journalctl gives a lot of gibberish I don't understand but one line in written in red:

`failed to load fecs_inst`

My system is a dualboot win 7-ubuntu 16.04 and it worked just fine before I turned it off while on vacation.

Answer (score 1):

If its an Asus there is a uefi bios setting that can cause this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2301908

Comment: The motherboard is msi

Comment: Please post the 'gibberish'

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer not knowing your computer make and model, your GPU's make and model and the drivers you are using (ie Nouveau or Nvidia). Because you can't boot the first option to try is to override Grub's kernel parameters by pressing `e` when grub provides a menu.

Then search for the line with `quiet splash` at the end and change it to `nomodeset quiet splash`.

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to continue booting Ubuntu.

If booting now works we need to trace what went wrong before. If booting doesn't work, there are lots of other overrides that can be applied but knowing which ones to try first depends what drivers are in place now, ie i915, Nouveau, Nvidia, AMD, etc.